# No sale JFRAME ni nada en consola

Tags: java, jframe

Hola como ejercicio estoy intentando programar un buscaminas. Creía que con lo que tenía hecho ya se debería ver al menos la ventana y todos los botones pero no es así y no entiendo que es lo que me falta. Cada vez que compilo no pasa absolutamente nada. (dejo el metodo cargarNumeros() x las dudas pero el error no debería estar ahí. aclaro xq es engorroso leerlo y no creo que sea necesario).  La idea es generar 100 botones de los cuales 20 van a ser bombas y al igual que en el buscaminas de windows, cada boton va a tener un número que indica cuantas bombas tiene alrededor (pudiendo ser 0 o más)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Recursividad extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    JButton contenedor [] [] = new JButton [10] [10]; 
    
Recursividad() {
    setLayout (null);
    for (int f = 0 ; f < 10 ; f++) {
 for(int c = 0; c< 10; c++) {
contenedor [f][c] = new JButton("0");       
contenedor [f] [c].setBounds (20 + c * 41, 50 + f * 41, 41, 41);
contenedor [f] [c].setBackground (Color.lightGray);
contenedor [f] [c].setForeground (Color.lightGray);
contenedor [f] [c].addActionListener (this);
add (contenedor [f] [c]);
    }
}   
cargarBombas();
cargarNumeros();
}

public void cargarBombas() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            int f = 0;
            int c = 0;
            do {
                f = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                c = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            } while (contenedor[f][c].getText() != "b");
    contenedor [f] [c].setText("b");
        }
}

public void cargarNumeros() {
    for(int f = 0; f < 10 ; f++ ) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10 ; c++)  {
    int contador = 0; 
    
    if (contenedor [f][c].getText() != "b")  {
    
            if (f -1 >= 0 && c-1 >= 0 && contenedor [f-1][c-1].getText() == "b" )
            contador++;
            if (c -1 >= 0 && contenedor [f-1][c].getText() == "b")
            contador++; 
            if (f +1 <= 9 && c -1 >= 0 && contenedor [f-1][c].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
            if (f +1 <= 9 && contenedor [f-1][c].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
            if (f +1 <= 9 && c+1 <= 9 && contenedor [f+1][c+1].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
            if (c +1 <= 9 && contenedor [f][c+1].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
            if (f -1 >= 0 && c+1 <= 9 && contenedor [f-1][c+1].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
            if (f -1 >= 0 && contenedor [f-1][c].getText() == "b")
                contador++;     
                
            contenedor [f][c].setText(String.valueOf(contador));    
    }
    
        }
    }   
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int f = 0 ; f < 10 ; f++) {
        
        for (int c = 0 ; c < 10 ; c++) {
            if (e.getSource () == contenedor [f] [c])
              {
                  if (contenedor [f] [c].getText ().equals ("b") == true)
                  {
                      setTitle ("Boooooooooooooomm");
                     // desactivarJuego ();
                  }
              
        }
    
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Recursividad p = new Recursividad();
        p.setBounds (0, 0, 470, 600);
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He corregido tu código para que muestre el Jframe
-solución: dentro del constructor agregar los metodos setVisible() y setBounds(), agregar un layout BorderLayout para ubicarlo al centro y que ocupe toda la ventana.

```
JButton contenedor[][] = new JButton[10][10];

public a() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 470, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            contenedor[f][c] = new JButton("0");
            contenedor[f][c].setBounds(20 + c * 41, 50 + f * 41, 41, 41);
            contenedor[f][c].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            contenedor[f][c].setForeground(Color.lightGray);
            contenedor[f][c].addActionListener(this);
            add(contenedor[f][c], BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
    cargarBombas();
    cargarNumeros();
}

public void cargarBombas() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        int f = 0;
        int c = 0;
        do {
            f = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            c = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        } while (contenedor[f][c].getText() != "b");
        contenedor[f][c].setText("b");
    }
}

public void cargarNumeros() {
    for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            int contador = 0;

            if (contenedor[f][c].getText() != "b") {

                if (f - 1 >= 0 && c - 1 >= 0 && contenedor[f - 1][c - 1].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (c - 1 >= 0 && contenedor[f - 1][c].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (f + 1 <= 9 && c - 1 >= 0 && contenedor[f - 1][c].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (f + 1 <= 9 && contenedor[f - 1][c].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (f + 1 <= 9 && c + 1 <= 9 && contenedor[f + 1][c + 1].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (c + 1 <= 9 && contenedor[f][c + 1].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (f - 1 >= 0 && c + 1 <= 9 && contenedor[f - 1][c + 1].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }
                if (f - 1 >= 0 && contenedor[f - 1][c].getText() == "b") {
                    contador++;
                }

                contenedor[f][c].setText(String.valueOf(contador));
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++) {

        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            if (e.getSource() == contenedor[f][c]) {
                if (contenedor[f][c].getText().equals("b") == true) {
                    setTitle("Boooooooooooooomm");
                    // desactivarJuego ();
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new a();
    
}
```

Resultado
[image: Ventana vista]

Comment: muchisimas gracias. preguntas: por que no me deja ponerlo en el main??? he visto mucha gente que lo hace de esa manera. Esa linea "new a" es completamente equivalente a poner Recursividad a = new Recursividad; ??

Comment: 1. La clase Recursividad hereda de JFrame, es decir ahora es un JFrame por lo que necesita tener sus atributos y métodos dentro del constructor, mientras que si creas una clase que no herede de JFrame, la puedes instanciar con un objeto directamente en el main: `JFrame f = new JFrame("Prueba");  f.setBounds();  f.setVisible();`  2. Para este ejemplo nombre a la clase *Recursividad* como **a**, siguiendo tu ejemplo seria equivalente a poner `new Recursividad();` esto para ahorrar gasto computacional ya que si instancias la clase con un objeto seria innecesario, pues no se usa